# Date, DateTime and the time zone

Tags: ruby, datetime, type-conversion

I have an application with a server time zone being BST (British Summer Time). When `Date` is created, the time zone is respected, as the time zone appears as BST (or `+01:00`) when the `Date` object is converted to a `Time` object (`in_time_zone` is rails method, but it is only used in the question to highlight the issue.):

```
Date.today.to_time  #=> 2014-09-16 00:00:00 +0100
Date.today.to_time.in_time_zone #=> Tue, 16 Sep 2014 00:00:00 BST +01:00
```

However, `DateTime` does not respect the time zone:

```
Date.today.to_datetime   #=> Tue, 16 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0000
```

and this will be translated to 1am by the server:

```
Date.today.to_datetime.in_time_zone #=> Tue, 16 Sep 2014 01:00:00 BST +01:00
```

Currently I do the following to force the correct time zone on datetime object:

```
Date.today.to_time.to_datetime  #=> Tue, 16 Sep 2014 00:00:00 +0100
```

but this feels wrong enough to put a comment in the code explaining why it is written like that.

Why does the conversion to `DateTime` behave differently than conversion to `Time`? Should it be treated as ruby bug or is it intentional behaviour?

Same issue occurs in irb. Tested in ruby-1.9.3-p448, ruby-2.1.0 and ruby-2.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this looks like an intended behaviour as this has been noted [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7445) and [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9794), and the author Tadayoshi Funaba has some comments on it in the discussion. Although, I (haven't read through, and) don't quite follow the logic (as well as the person asking it, and many others). Somehow, Tadayoshi Funaba seems to have gotten frustrated, and (probably because of this, intentionally,) the comments are mostly in Japanese even though the question was written in English.

Comment: Second link, comment #4 - priceless.

Comment: It looks like, in the end, [a patch](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/45822) was applied.